# Mariadb 10.1.26 recursive query

Tags: mysql, recursion, mariadb

I would like to run recursive query that will get all objects that are under `parent_object`.

The table looks like this:

```
id | name | price | parent_object
```

I would like to collect all total price of all children nodes that are under one node. Field that is in charge of defining who is under the node is `parent_node`. I am not able to use [WITH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/) syntax since `10.2.2` is the minimum version that supports recursive calls.

Can someone suggest how can I solve this in one query? What are your thoughts in terms of speed?

Comment: If you want "speed", you should use a more advanced tree schema like *materialized path* or *transitive closure*.

Comment: Are you calling MariaDB from a programming language?  If so a loop there could go down the layers of the tree.  If not, such could be simulated in a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guys in comments said, it seems like I have to use some more advanced tree schema, like `materialized path` or `transitive closure`. I decided to go for `materialized path`.